# Prove $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is maximal in $R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Problem**

Prove that the ideal <$x^2+1$> is maximal in $R[x]$

**Attempt**

Assume $A$ is an ideal of $R[x]$.

*My attempt is to show that $A$ contains some non-zero real number $c$. Then $(1/c) c \in A$ and therefore A=R[x].*

Let $f(x) \in A $ ,but $f(x) \notin $     <$x^2+1$>.
Then $f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1)+r(x)$, where $r(x) \neq 0$ and degree of $r(x)$ is less than 2. It follows that $r(x)=ax+b$,where a and b are not both zero .

$ax+b= r(x)-q(x)(x^2+1) \in A$.

If $(ax-b)(ax+b) \in A$ ,then

$a^2x^2-b^2 \in A$ and $a^2x^2+x^2 \in A$. From these two we get $0\neq a^2+b^2 \in A$

**Doubt**

Are there any shorter proof for this? I am trying to attempt another proof by using this theorem .

**Theorem**

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $A$ be an ideal of $R$. Then $R/A$ is a field if and only if $A$ is maximal

Comment: $\mathbb R[x]$ is a PID, so $(x^2+1)$ is maximal iff $x^2+1$ is prime, which occurs iff it has no roots, which is obvious.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if this is any shorter, but you can show $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2+1)\cong \mathbb C$, a field, so the theorem implies $(x^2+1)$ is maximal.

Comment: Why $\Bbb Z$ in the title?

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: In your proof, how do you know that $ax-b \in A$?

Comment: By mistake i added 'and' in between $ax-b$ and $ax+b$ . Thanks for pointing it out.